# How to direct pass HTML Form fields as an array to database in CodeIgniter using JQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

this is my view page:

```
<form role="form" id="addNewMatter" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>saveNewSupplier" 
method="post">

<input type="text" value="" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="text" value="" name="phone" id="phone" />
<input type="text" value="" name="email" id="email" />
<input type="text" value="" name="address" id="address" />

<script>
   $('form').change(function() {
       var input = $('form').serializeArray();
       var data = "";
       $( "#formdata" ).empty();
       jQuery.each( input, function( i, input1 ) {
        if($(this).attr("name") !== 'formdata'){
         data += "\"" + $(this).attr("name") + "\"=>" +  "\"" + input1.value +  "\",";
        }
           finaldata = data.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
           $( "#formdata" ).val( finaldata );
           //alert($(this).attr('name'));
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" value="" name="formdata" id="formdata" />
</form>
```

and this is my controller page:

```
function saveNewSupplier()
{

    $createdby= $this->vendorId;
    $createddate= date('d M Y');

            $formdata = $this->input->post('formdata');
$Info = array();
    $Info = array($formdata, 'createdby'=>$createdby,
   'createddate'=>$createddate);
$this->load->model('user_model');
$result = $this->user_model->saveNewSupplier($Info);
}
```

and this is my model page :

```
function saveNewSupplier($Info)
{
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('tbl_suppliers1', $Info);

    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->trans_complete();

    return $insert_id;
}
```

insert query is not working it shows `0` as 1st column in array but it should be the array which i passed from view through post method.
please help me to fix this insert query. thanks.

Comment: anyone figured out something yet?

Comment: i used &apos; instead of single ' query \' got fixed but still not working still showing 0 at 1st column and $formdata as its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->input->post()` will give you the form fields as an array, so you can do this without using any javascript.

If your `tbl_suppliers1` table has columns "formdata", "createdby", "createddate":

```
function saveNewSupplier()
{
    $createdby = $this->vendorId;
    $createddate = date('d M Y');

    $form = $this->input->post();
    $data = array(
        json_encode($form),
        'createdby' => $createdby,
        'createddate' => $createddate
    );
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $result = $this->user_model->saveNewSupplier($data);
}
```

If your `tbl_supplier` has columns "name", "phone", (etc), "createddate":

```
function saveNewSupplier()
{
    $createdby = $this->vendorId;
    $createddate = date('d M Y');

    $form = $this->input->post();
    $data = $form;
    $data['createdby'] = $createdby;
    $data['createddate'] = $createddate;
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $result = $this->user_model->saveNewSupplier($data);
}
```

Keep in mind neither your script method or the above examples check for valid fields.

Comment: how do i post table data in form from view to controller?

Comment: @Danial What do you mean by "table data"? There is no such thing as a table input in a form.

Comment: after saving my data in master table I have to insert its relevant data in detail table(multiple rows) so i used simple html table in form where I can input multiple rows, I want to save them in detail table using master table primary key. I have the master table primary key from this->db->insert_id() but how do I post that html table data to detail table, thanks.

Comment: I used this to make table td editable `ondblclick="this.contentEditable=true; this.className='inEdit'; this.focus();"`